# Kotlin 1.3.50 Parcelize unresolved reference error

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-experimental

Working my first android app, kotlin 1.3.50. I initially implemented Parcelable, but switched to parcelize and then added the enums.   Here is my data class

```
package com.igniterobotics.scouting_2019.Models

import android.os.Parcel
import android.os.Parcelable
import com.igniterobotics.scouting_2019.Enums.Movement
import com.igniterobotics.scouting_2019.Enums.Preload
import com.igniterobotics.scouting_2019.Enums.StartingPosition

@Parcelize
data class AutonResult(var hatchCount: Int, var cargoCount: Int, 
      var intakeDrop: Int, var itemDrops: Int, var startingPosision: StartingPosition, 
      var preload: Preload, var movement: Movement
)
```

One question mentioned plugin order in the build.gradle as a source for the issue.  Here's mine

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
```

Any idea why I @Parcelize can't be resolved?

Comment: You are missing the experimental flag https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/android-plugin.html#enabling-experimental-features

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
       ....
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            ...
        }
    }

    androidExtensions {
        experimental = true
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  I'll test this in a couple of hours.  This is a personal project I'm working on.

Comment: I had added the androidExtensions at the root level and not a child of android node.  Additionall, my data class didn't have : Parcelable at the end.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add

```
androidExtensions {
        experimental = true
    }
```

In your app's build.gradle

Comment: I tried adding it after the plugins, Is that in the correct location?  I haven't worked with gradle files much, since I most do C# development.  If that's the correct place, maybe I had a typo or something.

Comment: Add it inside the android{...} Tag

Answer (score 1):

If you're still facing this issue in 2021 you can follow this

Don’t forget that Parcelize feature in Kotlin is part of the `kotlin-android-extensions` compiler plugin, so removing the plugin will end up making all your Parcelable classes not compiling if they depend on the Parcelize annotation.
JetBrains extracted the Parcelize from Kotlin Android Extensions to a new plugin,

```
kotlin-parcelize
```

First you will need to add `kotlin-parcelize` plugin to your module.

```
plugins {
    ..
    id 'kotlin-parcelize'
}
```

Then change your old import statement from

```
import kotlinx.android.parcel.Parcelize
```

to

```
import kotlinx.parcelize.Parcelize
```

Example

```
    import kotlinx.parcelize.Parcelize
    import android.os.Parcelable

    @Parcelize
    class User(val name: String, val age: Int): Parcelable
```

[more](https://proandroiddev.com/migrating-the-deprecated-kotlin-android-extensions-compiler-plugin-to-viewbinding-d234c691dec7)